# How to pull specific key from this nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{
    "newData": [{
                "env1": [{
                            "sins": [{
                                "host": "test.com",
                                "deployTime": "2015-07-23 11:54 AM",
                                …
                            }],
                            "name": “hello”
                        }, 
                {
                 "env1": [{
                             "sins": [{
                                 "host": "test.com",
                                 "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM",
                                            …
                            }],
                            "name": "hello"
```

I am trying to pull the 'host' and the 'name' from this nested dictionary.

I only know how to get 'name' and append to a list, but I want to append both name and 'host'.

Currently I am doing

```
list=[]
for row in my_dict['newData']:
    list.append(row)
for i in list:
    print i['name']
```

Comment: Did you really mean to have the `for i in list` loop nested inside `for row in my_dict`?

Comment: no sorry, i am editing this now

Comment: I'm also not sure you have the dictionary nesting right. Is the second `env1` really nested inside the first one?

Comment: Please provide a MVE, with input and output so we can help.

Comment: the second env1 is not nested.

Comment: i adjusted the spacing so it is easier to read..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Chad.  If I print the output I get "hello", "hello" as expected.  I'm just trying to figure out how to grab the values for "host" inside "sins".

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is utterly broken. Please post at least an upright structure. Assuming it should look like this:

```
test= {"newData": [{"env1": [{"sins": [{"host": "test.com",
                                        "deployTime": "2015-07-23 11:54 AM",}],
                              "name": "hello"}]}, 
                   {"env1": [{"sins": [{"host": "test.com",
                                        "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM",}],
                              "name": "hello"}]}]}
```

then this:

```
print([element['env1'][0]['sins'][0]['host'] + ' ' \
        + element['env1'][0]['name'] for element in test['newData']])
```

would yield:

```
['test.com hello', 'test.com hello']
```