# How to parse through a nest of nested JSON?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am stuck using this API at my work, and having trouble parsing through the dataset because of it's complexity.

In the following JSON, the only values of any importance to me are "name" and the actual host name.  I am trying to make a dictionary that consists of {"name":"host, host, host, host"}.  If anyone knows how to parse through this or can point me in the right direction, that would be very much appreciated.

```
{

    "hugeData":[
    {

        "env1":[
        {

            "sins":[
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-225.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-07-23 11:54 AM", "sin": "0"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-129-193.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-09-01 01:09 PM", "sin": "7"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-235.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-07-23 11:54 AM", "sin": "9"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-250.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-07-23 11:53 AM", "sin": "12"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-223.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-07-23 11:53 AM", "sin": "14"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-237.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-07-23 11:54 AM", "sin": "17"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-244.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-07-23 11:53 AM", "sin": "18"},
            ],

            "status": "success",

            "buildTime": "2015-05-26T17:06:06",

        }
        ],

        "name": "apache-6"
        },

    {
        "env1":[
        {
            "sins":[
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-225.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM", "sin": "0"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-129-193.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM", "sin": "7"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-235.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM", "sin": "9"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-250.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM", "sin": "12"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-223.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM", "sin": "14"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-237.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM", "sin": "17"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-244.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM", "sin": "18"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-248.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-12-16 05:23 PM", "sin": "21"},
            ],

            "status": "success",

            "buildTime": "2015-12-16T17:07:44",
        }
        ],

        "name": "apache-5"
        },

    {
        "env1":[
        {
            "sins":[
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-234.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-08-06 03:13 PM", "sin": "10"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-246.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-08-06 03:15 PM", "sin": "20"},
            {"host": "ip-10-12-138-216.va1.b2c.test.com", "deployTime": "2015-08-06 03:04 PM", "sin": "28"}
            ],

            "status": "success",

            "buildTime": "2013-02-21T15:41:59",

        }
        ],

        "name": "app-steel"
        },
}
```

Comment: Trying to figure out why this question reminds me of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953802/how-to-pull-specific-key-from-this-nested-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you like the answer this time.

(assigned dict/json to a varibale named test)

```
your_dict = {i['name']: ", ".join([host['host'] for host in i['env1'][0]['sins']]) \
              for i in test["hugeData"]}
```

Comment: What is the reason for the line spacing/indentation in the second line?  Is the "for i" line supposed to have that large of an indentation?

Comment: It is all one expression. The `\\` at the end of the first line tells the interpreter that the expression will continue in the next line. I just did that to prevent SO from adding the scroll bar for this code section. The indentation is just for someone reading the code. It is not needed.